# Adding and not Updating User Roles

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to update the User Roles from a drop down. When I select the username (email address) and the role( ex. SuperUser, Admin, User) that I want to assign them and hit submit I submits everything as it should. What I have found is that for ever role I select for the same user to update it creates a data entry for that role and adds the user more that once. This makes it so that the last record entered in is always the userRole.

What I cant figure out is how once i find the user, to delete the current RoleId and add the new one.

If you would like any of the other code from the View, Model or anything else please let me know and ill post it.

Image at bottom for example of whats happening in the DB.

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> RegisterRole(RegisterViewModel model, ApplicationUser user)
    {

        var userId = db.AspNetUsers.Where(i => i.UserName == user.UserName).Select(s => s.Id);
        string updateId = "";
        foreach (var i in userId)
        {
            updateId = i.ToString();
        }
        //Assign Role to user here
        await this.UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(updateId, model.Name);

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Employee");
    }
```

[image: Repeat records]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two methods that can come handy to you : 1) [GetRolesAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn497559(v=vs.108).aspx)  to get all the user roles, and 2) delete them all using [RemoveFromRoleAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn497577(v=vs.108).aspx) before Adding new Role

```
var roles = await this.UserManager.GetRolesAsync(userId);
await this.UserManager.RemoveFromRolesAsync(userId, roles.ToArray());

//then add new role 
await this.UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(userId, roleName);
```

Edit:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> RegisterRole(RegisterViewModel model, ApplicationUser user)
{

    //in case user is being passed in without Id (unlikely), you could use user manager to get the full user object 
    //user = await this.UserManager.FindByNameAsync(user.UserName);

    //get all user's roles, and remove them
    var roles = await this.UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user.Id);
    await this.UserManager.RemoveFromRolesAsync(user.Id, roles.ToArray());

    //Assign Role to user here
    await this.UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, model.Name);

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Employee");
}
```

Comment: and i would put these after the foreach loop correct?

Comment: yes, but why are you running doing a foreach? seem to that you are already getting a user passed in, so you could just use user.Id for userId. I am going to edit my answer.

Comment: Works like a champ! Thank you kind sir! The only thing I had to change was the `FindUserByNameAsync` line of code to `to FindByNameAsync`.

Comment: Glad I could help, I'll edit my answer to make that change.